# NumPy maxima of groups defined by a label array

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays, one is a list of values and one is a list of IDs corresponding to each value. Some IDs have multiple values. I want to create a new array that contains the maximum value recorded for each id, which will have a length equal to the number of unique ids.

Example using a `for` loop:

```
import numpy as np

values = np.array([5, 3, 2, 6, 3, 4, 8, 2, 4, 8])
ids = np.array([0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6])

uniq_ids = np.unique(ids)
maximums = np.ones_like(uniq_ids) * np.nan

for i, id in enumerate(uniq_ids):
    maximums[i] = np.max(values[np.where(ids == id)])

print(uniq_ids)
print(maximums)
```

```
[0 1 3 5 6]
[5. 3. 6. 8. 8.]
```

Is it possible to vectorize this so it runs fast? I'm imagining a one-liner that can create the "maximums" array using only NumPy functions, but I haven't been able to come up with anything that works.

Comment: You probably don't need the `where`, `values[ids==id]`.  But for each `id`, that selection will differ in length.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`np.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) sorts by multiple columns. However, this is not compulsory. You can sort `ids` first and then choose maximum item of each divided group using [`numpy.maximum.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html)

```
def mathfux(values, ids, return_groups=False):
    argidx = np.argsort(ids) #70% time
    ids_sort, values_sort = ids[argidx], values[argidx] #4% time
    div_points = np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(ids_sort)) + 1] #11% time (the most part for np.flatnonzero)
    if return_groups: 
        return ids[div_points], np.maximum.reduceat(values_sort, div_points)
    else: return np.maximum.reduceat(values_sort, div_points)

mathfux(values, ids, return_groups=True)
>>> (array([0, 1, 3, 5, 6]), array([5, 3, 6, 8, 8]))
mathfux(values, ids)
>>> mathfux(values, ids)
array([5, 3, 6, 8, 8])
```

Usually, some parts of `numpy` codes could be optimised further in `numba`. Note that [`np.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) is a bottleneck in majority of groupby problems which can't be replaced by any other method. It is unlikely to be improved soon in `numba` or `numpy`. So you are reaching an optimal performance here and can't do much in further optimisations.

Answer (score 5):

Use `np.lexsort` to sort both lists simultaneously:

```
idx = np.lexsort([values, ids])
```

The indices of the last unique ID are given by

```
last = np.r_[np.flatnonzero(np.diff(ids[idx])), len(ids) - 1]
```

You can use this to get the maxima of each group:

```
values[idx[last]]
```

This is the same as `values[idx][last]`, but faster because you only need to extract `len(last)` elements this way, instead of rearranging the whole array and then extracting.

Keep in mind that `np.unique` is basically doing `sort` and `flatnonzero` when you do `return_index=True`.

Here's a collection of all the solutions so far, along with a benchmark. I suggest a modified solution to [@bb1's pandas recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70965356/2988730) implemented below.

```
def Shannon(values, ids):
    uniq_ids = np.unique(ids)
    maxima = np.ones_like(uniq_ids) * np.nan
    for i, id in enumerate(uniq_ids):
        maxima[i] = np.max(values[np.where(ids == id)])
    return maxima

def richardec(values, ids):
    return [a.max() for a in np.split(values, np.arange(1, ids.shape[0])[(np.diff(ids) != 0)])]

def MadPhysicist(values, ids):
    idx = np.lexsort([values, ids])
    return values[idx[np.r_[np.flatnonzero(np.diff(ids[idx])), len(ids) - 1]]]

def PeptideWitch(values, ids):
    return np.vectorize(lambda id: np.max(values[np.where(ids == id)]))(np.unique(ids))

def mathfux(values, ids):
    idx = np.argsort(ids)
    return np.maximum.reduceat(values[idx], np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(np.diff(ids[idx])) + 1])

def bb1(values, ids):
    return DataFrame({'ids': ids, 'vals': values}).groupby('ids')['values'].max().to_numpy()

def bb1_modified(values, ids):
    return Series(values).groupby(ids).max().to_numpy()
```

```
values = np.array([5, 3, 2, 6, 3, 4, 8, 2, 4, 8])
ids = np.array([0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6])

%timeit Shannon(values, ids)
42.1 µs ± 561 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit richardec(values, ids)
27.7 µs ± 181 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit MadPhysicist(values, ids)
19.3 µs ± 268 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit PeptideWitch(values, ids)
55.9 µs ± 1.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit mathfux(values, ids)
20.9 µs ± 308 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit bb1(values, ids)
865 µs ± 34.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit bb1_modified(values, ids)
537 µs ± 3.36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
values = np.random.randint(10000, size=10000)
ids = np.random.randint(100, size=10000)

%timeit Shannon(values, ids)
1.76 ms ± 13.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit richardec(values, ids)
29.1 ms ± 510 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
%timeit MadPhysicist(values, ids)
904 µs ± 20 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit PeptideWitch(values, ids)
1.74 ms ± 16.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit mathfux(values, ids)
372 µs ± 3.54 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit bb1(values, ids)
964 µs ± 9.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit bb1_modified(values, ids)
679 µs ± 7.86 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

@mathfux's suggestion of using `np.maximum.reduceat` is by far the fastest all around, followed by the modified pandas solution and then lexsorting. The pandas solution is likely very similar to the `reduceat` one, but with a lot more overhead. You can see that the incremental change for the modified pandas solution is tiny because of that.

For large arrays (which are the only ones that matter), it seems that finding the maxima individually is comparable to the question, while richardec's comprehension is much slower, despite the fact that it does not sort the input values according to the IDs.

Comment: I think you can do `np.diff(ids)` instead of `np.diff(ids[idx])`, no?

Comment: @richardec. That's just because `%timeit` magic uses powers of 10 to get to 2 sec of total runtime, and mine is just under 20us, while yours is just over.

Comment: @richardec. Only if it's already sorted, which I'm not assuming.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I think I understand what your solution is doing, except the `np.r_` bit, can you explain that? If I wanted to change this to return the min value instead of max, how would I identify the first value for each ID rather than the last?

Comment: @Shannon. `np.flatnonzero(np.diff(ids[idx]))` returns the index of the location before the `ids` value changes. That happens to be the last element of each group, except for the last one. `np.r_[that, len(ids) - 1]` just appends a scalar to that array. You can also write it as `np.concatenate((that, [len(ids) - 1]))`.

Comment: @Shannon. To get the minima, you'll want to get the start of each group. That's given by `np.flatnonzero(np.diff(ids[idx])) + 1`, except for the first group. To fix that, use `np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(...)]`. I recommend you break those statements up and look at all the indices and diffs to make sure you know what each part is doing and why.

Comment: what about [`np.maximum.reduceat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html)?

Comment: @mathfux. Good call. I'll add that in too.

Comment: @mathfux. 2.5x faster, as expected. Added to the benchmark. Well seen!

Comment: @Shannon. Use mathfux's suggestion. A sample implementation is shown above. This time, we do `np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(...) + 1]` to get the end start and end indices of each group to reduce over.

Comment: Note that `np.r_[0, np.flatnonzero(...) + 1]` has a nice name `div_points` somewhere in the source code of `np.split` method. Also note that `np.split` calls `list.append` for each sublist which is not efficient if there are many sublists.

Comment: @mathfux. Nice find.

Comment: This is awesome. Thankyou!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution, which, although not 100% vectorized, (per my benchmarks) takes about half the time as your does (using your sample data). The performance improvement probably becomes more drastic with more data:

```
maximums = [a.max() for a in np.split(values, np.arange(1, ids.shape[0])[(np.diff(ids) != 0)])]
```

Output:

```
>>> maximums
[5, 3, 6, 8, 8]
```

Comment: This is twice as fast on very small data, but unfortunately 15-20x slower for larger data.

Comment: Darn. Wow, so yours is the fastest! Congrats!

Comment: Second fastest, as it turns out. @mathfux leaves mine in the dust.

Answer (score 1):

In trying to visualize the problem:

```
In [82]: [np.where(ids==id) for id in uniq_ids]
Out[82]: 
[(array([0]),),
 (array([1]),),
 (array([2, 3, 4, 5]),),
 (array([6]),),
 (array([7, 8, 9]),)]
```

`unique` can also return:

```
In [83]: np.unique(ids, return_inverse=True)
Out[83]: (array([0, 1, 3, 5, 6]), array([0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]))
```

Which is a variante on what `richardec` produced:

```
In [88]: [a for a in np.split(ids, np.arange(1, ids.shape[0])[(np.diff(ids) !=
    ...: 0)])]
Out[88]: [array([0]), array([1]), array([3, 3, 3, 3]), array([5]), array([6, 6, 6])]
```

That inverse is also produced by doing `where` on all `==` at once:

```
In [90]: ids[:,None] == uniq_ids
Out[90]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False,  True]])
In [91]: np.nonzero(ids[:,None] == uniq_ids)
Out[91]: (array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]), array([0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4]))
```

I'm still thinking through this ...

Comment: Why not just lexsort and pick out the maxima based on the last index of each group? If you're using `unique`, you're already sorting anyway. I posted an answer BTW

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT: I'll leave this up as an example of why we can't always use np.vectorize() to make everything magically faster:*

One solution is to use numpy's vectorize function:

```
import numpy as np

values = np.array([5, 3, 2, 6, 3, 4, 8, 2, 4, 8])
ids = np.array([0, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 6, 6, 6])

def my_func(id):
    return np.max(values[np.where(ids==id)])

vector_func = np.vectorize(my_func)
maximums = vector_func(np.unique(ids))
```

which returns

```
array([5, 3, 6, 8, 8])
```

But as for speed, your version has about the same performance when we use

```
values = np.array([random.randint(1, 100) for i in range(1000000)])
ids = []
for i in range(100000):
    r = random.randint(1, 4)
    if r == 3:
        for x in range(3):
            ids.append(i)
    elif r == 2:
        for x in range(4):
            ids.append(i)
    else:
        ids.append(i)
ids = np.array(ids)
```

It's about 12 seconds per execution.

Comment: This actually seems a little _slower_ than the OP's solution. ?!?

Comment: Interesting isn't it. I guess it's because of `values[np.where(ids==id)]`, which I'm thinking is a bottleneck for the vectorised function

Comment: For small arrays, all bets are off, but for large ones, yours is the same speed as OP's and much faster than richardec's. Mine's fastest regardless.

Answer (score 1):

With pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

def with_pandas(ids, vals):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'ids': ids, 'vals': values})
    return df.groupby('ids')['vals'].max().to_numpy()
```

Timing:

```
import numpy as np

values = np.random.randint(10000, size=10000)
ids = np.random.randint(100, size=10000)

%timeit with_pandas(ids, values)
692 µs ± 21.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: Nice. I added your implementation and a faster version to my benchmark: `pd.Series(values).groupby(ids).max().to_numpy()`. The cool thing about pandas is that it's really fast if you're willing to accept the massive overhead of making Series compared to working with arrays.